# Javascript: how to target a variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, variables

So I have a set of variables ending with numbers and I want to target each variable and remove and add a class dynamically. I can't seme to figure it out, any ideas?

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
    img2 = document.getElementById('img2'),
    img3 = document.getElementById('img3'),
    img4 = document.getElementById('img4');
    counter = 0;

 for(i=1; i < 5; i++){
        counter++;
        img+counter.classList.remove('hideImg');
        img+counter.classList.add('showImg');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the images in an array or object and iterate through the elements - you can access them via their index or key.

Here's an example with an array:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
img2 = document.getElementById('img2'),
img3 = document.getElementById('img3'),
img4 = document.getElementById('img4');

var images = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].classList.remove('hideImg');
  images[i].classList.add('showImg');
}
```

Here's an example with an object:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
img2 = document.getElementById('img2'),
img3 = document.getElementById('img3'),
img4 = document.getElementById('img4');

var images = {
  img1: img1,
  img2: img2,
  img3: img3,
  img4: img4
};

for (imagekey in images) {
  images[imageKey].classList.remove('hideImg');
  images[imageKey].classList.add('showImg');
}
```

Here's an example with an array, and only showing one image at a time with a delay in between:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
img2 = document.getElementById('img2'),
img3 = document.getElementById('img3'),
img4 = document.getElementById('img4');

var images = [img1, img2, img3, img4];
var i = 0;

setInterval(cycleImage, 3000);

function cycleImage() {
  images[i].classList.remove('hideImg');
  images[i].classList.add('showImg');
  if (i === images.length) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked but now how do I show the images with a delay between each other? I dont want the images to all show at the same time.

Comment: you can create a function that does the class toggling and increments the imageKey by 1, then run that on setTimeout. will update answer with that

Comment: @FrankDTankDeLeon did that help?

Answer (score 0):

If the name is always going to follow the convention of 'img' + index we can just do

```
for(i=1; i < 5; i++){
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + i);

        img.classList.remove('hideImg');
        img.classList.add('showImg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about giving them same classname and retrieve by `ClassName` function and do `remove & add` actions.

```js
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img');       
 for(var counter=0; counter < img.length; counter++){        
        img[counter].classList.remove('hideImg');
        img[counter].classList.add('showImg');
}
```

```css
.showImg {
    display : block;
    }
  .hideImg {
    display : none;
    }
```

```html
<img class="img hideImg" alt="img1">
<img class="img hideImg" alt="img2">
<img class="img hideImg" alt="img3">
<img class="img hideImg" alt="img4">
```

Answer (score 0):

`[id^=img]` selector match all elements which has `id` starts with `img` .

so, let your code be more dynamic and elegant :

```
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=img]'))
   .forEach(({classList}) => {
      classList.remove('hideImg');
      classList.add('showImg');
   }) ;
```

```js
     Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=img]')).forEach(({id, classList}) => {
        console.log('showing ', id );
        classList.remove('hideImg');
        classList.add('showImg');
    }) ;
```

```css
.showImg {
    display : block;
    }
  .hideImg {
    display : none;
    }
```

```html
<img id="img1" class="hideImg" alt="img1">
<img id="img2" class="hideImg" alt="img2">
<img id="img3" class="hideImg" alt="img3">
<img id="img4" class="hideImg" alt="img4">
```